# Murge 2 columns Table data in 1 column of Combobox

Tags: sql, combobox, ms-access-2007

I have a combo box and a table MyTable
MyTable:

```
ID ¦ A ¦ B ¦
-------------
1  ¦ 1 ¦ 4 ¦
2  ¦ 2 ¦ 5 ¦
3  ¦ 3 ¦ 6 ¦
```

I have managed to get values in combobox like this.

```
Row Source = select A, B from MyTable
```

Relult:

```
1 ¦ 4
2 ¦ 5
3 ¦ 6
```

But i want to murge these 2 columns in one column and want to show like this.

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

I am sorry if its a repeated question but i have searched for my answer and didn't find my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Union All, Query will be as below:

```
select A as Colmn from MyTable
Union All
select B as Colmn from MyTable
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE     @MyTable    TABLE   (ID int, A int, B int)
INSERT INTO @MyTable    VALUES
            (1, 1, 4)
        ,   (2, 2, 5)
        ,   (3, 3, 6)

SELECT  Output = A  FROM @MyTable
UNION
SELECT  Output = B  FROM @MyTable
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add ORDER BY ASC at the end, 
to be sure if the data are not arranged in the order in the table.

`select a as 'a-b' from MyTable
union
select b as 'a-b' from MyTable
order by 'a-b' asc`

Or [demo.](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vga2bt7VZTP3JiBtSUwznF/0)

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get my solution using VN'sCorner solution

```
Row Source = select A as Colmn from MyTable
Union All
select B as Colmn from MyTable
```

And boom i have an output
Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```